# Secure push and pull with no password GIT

Tags: git, raspberry-pi, git-shell

I am working on my raspberry pi server and whenever I clone or do anything on the gitremotely I want to disable password on the push and pull.
How do I do that?
I don't want to enter password on git shell when I try to pull or push any changes to the server.

Comment: "I want to disable the push and pull" What do you mean by that? That statement seems to conflict with what you are saying in the remainder of your question.

Comment: Also, are you pushing to GitHub or to your Raspberry PI server? Or are you SSH'd into your Raspberry PI server and pushing from there to GitHub? Please clarify your question. As-is it's very confusing.

Comment: I am pushing to Raspberry Pi server from git hub using git push origin master and it asks for a password. Also, I have corrected the question, I meant to say disable password on push and pull

Comment: Uh... you can't push *from* GitHub. GitHub doesn't let you SSH into their servers. I'm guessing GitHub (https://github.com/) has nothing to do with this question and you're just using git without GitHub?

Comment: Yes sorry I am new to this, so I did not know the difference

Comment: No problem. In my experience that's a fairly common mistake. I've posted an answer below that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to generate your SSH keys (like @Ajedi32 exlains) or like is explained on github page : https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys

Also currently if you type
`git remote -v`
you will see that your repository (`origin` probably) will have pathes starting with `https://github.com/user/repo.git`). This means that git on your local machine is referring to *remote git repo* via `https`. When referring to the *remote git repo* via `https`, git will ALWAYS ask for password.

This is why AFTER you have set up the SSH keys as described in one of the methods above, you must change the way git is referring to the *remote repo* from `https` protocol to `ssh` protocol.

To do that you first have to write down you current repo path, eg.
`https://github.com/username/reponame.git`
then you can convert it to the `ssh` style address:
`ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git`   (mind that you only have to change `username` and `reponame` parts. Leave `git@github.com` as it is. It always must be like this.

Then on your local machine you can type the following code:
If you're on linux

```
git remote -v
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin ssh://git@github.com/username/reponame.git
git remote -v
```

The last command will print you the path via which git refers to the *remote repository* and it will be starting with `ssh://...`.

Mind that when using command `git remote -v` the repository path will be printed twice, once for `fetch` and once with  `push` comment.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not certain what your exact set up is, but it sounds to me like you want to set up an SSH key on your server. The [Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book) book covers how to do this quite thoroughly in [Chapter 4.4](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server):

> Let’s walk through setting up SSH access on the server side. In this
>   example, you’ll use the authorized_keys method for authenticating your
>   users. We also assume you’re running a standard Linux distribution
>   like Ubuntu. First, you create a 'git' user and a .ssh directory for
>   that user.
>
> ```
> $ sudo adduser git
> $ su git
> $ cd
> $ mkdir .ssh
> ```
>
> Next, you need to add some developer SSH public keys to the
>   authorized_keys file for that user. Let’s assume you’ve received a few
>   keys by e-mail and saved them to temporary files. Again, the public
>   keys look something like this:
>
> ```
> $ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub
> ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQCB007n/ww+ouN4gSLKssMxXnBOvf9LGt4L
> ojG6rs6hPB09j9R/T17/x4lhJA0F3FR1rP6kYBRsWj2aThGw6HXLm9/5zytK6Ztg3RPKK+4k
> Yjh6541NYsnEAZuXz0jTTyAUfrtU3Z5E003C4oxOj6H0rfIF1kKI9MAQLMdpGW1GYEIgS9Ez
> Sdfd8AcCIicTDWbqLAcU4UpkaX8KyGlLwsNuuGztobF8m72ALC/nLF6JLtPofwFBlgc+myiv
> O7TCUSBdLQlgMVOFq1I2uPWQOkOWQAHukEOmfjy2jctxSDBQ220ymjaNsHT4kgtZg2AYYgPq
> dAv8JggJICUvax2T9va5 gsg-keypair
> ```
>
> You just append them to your authorized_keys file:
>
> ```
> $ cat /tmp/id_rsa.john.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> $ cat /tmp/id_rsa.josie.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> $ cat /tmp/id_rsa.jessica.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
> ```